# More elegant way of specifying a `str` conditional on two (or more) other variables

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement

I would like to specify a str (which will be used as a filename) conditional on two other variables. Suppose I have a base name (specified as a str type), `file_name = 'filename.txt'`; and I have two variables, `x` and `y`, which may either be `NoneType` or `str`. What I expect may be achieved by the folllowing code:

```
if x == None and y == None:
    file_name = 'filename.txt'
elif x == 'abc' and y == None:
    file_name = 'filename_abc.txt'
elif x == None and y == 'def':
    file_name = 'filename_def.txt'
else: # both x and y are str
    file_name = 'filename_{}_{}.txt'.format(x, y)
```

So basically, if `x` (or `y`) is a non-NoneType str, there should be an additional underscore `_` in the `file_name`. I can understand that using `if` and `elif` statements could achieve the goal. But what if there are more than two (say 10) conditional variables like `x` and `y`? It would be quite lengthy. I was wondering if there would be any more elegant way of doing that.

Comment: `If` with an uppercase?

Comment: Also you have assignment not equality comparison.

Comment: Furthermore equality is checked with **`==`**, not `=`...

Comment: you really want to check against `abc` and `def` or just against `str` type?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Just `str` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
bits = [s for s in (x, y) if not s is None]
file_name = '_'.join(['filename'] + bits) + '.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

just put your parameters in a `list`, and filter out `None` type, join strings, just use `format` to insert the composite string:

```
params = [None,"abc",None,"def",12]

filename = "filename{}.txt".format("".join(["_{}".format(p) for p in params if p is not None]))


print(filename)
```

This solution can convert other parameters like integers if found in your list (like `format` would do) and also works properly (with a little help from Paul :)) with there are only `None` parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I think your method now is the same but coded in different ways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use some conditional expressions:

```
fx = '_{}'.format(x) if x else ''
fy = '_{}'.format(y) if y else ''
filename = 'filename{}{}.txt'.format(fx, fy)
```

this explicitly checks the boolness of `x` and `y` and then calls format, so any non-false values for `x` and `y` apply.

If you only need strings, replace `if x` with `if isinstance(x, str)` and similarly for `y`.

Comment: Thanks Jim for help.